# How to make data trending attribute dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am using data-trending="abc" in menu href in html5. But now, I am moving website in wordpress and want to make menu in wp but same effect style. Here is the link reference website:- http://www.theladbible.com/. I want exact menu in wp. My problem is I do not know how to merge data trending with wp menu dynamically:

here is my code:

```
<section class="primary-nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-funny" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/funny">Funny</a></li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-entertainment" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/category/entertainment">Entertainment</a></li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-news" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-tech" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/technology">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-videos" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/videos">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-pictures" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/pictures">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a data-trending="trending-summer" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/summer">TheSUMMERbible</a>
            <span style="margin-left: 0.2em; padding-left: 0.2em; border-left: 1px solid #eee;margin-top: 0;">
                <img src="http://www1.theladbible.com/images/content/55b680a5d9a22.png" style="max-height: 1em; vertical-align: top;">
            </span>
        </li>
    <li><a data-trending="trending-more" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/more">More</a></li>

    <li><a href="http://www.theoddsbible.com/?utm_source=theladbible.com&amp;utm_medium=channel&amp;utm_campaign=TheLadBible" target="_blank">TheOddsBible</a></li>

    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/submit-your-content/">Submit Your Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="trending-nav">

    <div class="trending-content trending-funny">
    <section class="trending">content</section>
<div>
<script>
$('a[data-trending]', sixty520.nav).hover(function (e) {
      var el = $(e.target);
      var trendingList = el.data('trending');
      $('.trending-content', sixty520.nav).hide();
      $('.' + trendingList).show();
    });

  }
</script>
```

Now I want to convert this menu in wp menu I know how to make menu in wp but dnt know about how to merge data trending with wp menu.

Kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: What is data trending?

Comment: you can say it data attribute, function is= access menu content relevant div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your menus page in wp-admin, click on the sreen options and check the "CSS styles" box(if not active already) and "Link Relationship (XFN)". After doing this you will be able to add specific class name for your menu's `<li>` elements and rel attribute for `<a>` elements where you can edit each element's properties.

if you change your jQuery code like the one below, it should work as you want.

```
<script>

$('li.trending a', sixty520.nav).hover(function (e) {
      var el = $(e.target);
      var trendingList = el.attr('rel');
      $('.trending-content', sixty520.nav).hide();
      $('.' + trendingList).show();
    });

  }
</script>
```

So you have to give `.trending` class to `<li>` elements from WP's "CSS style" field and enter the desired value(eg. trending-funny, trending-entertainment) to "Link Relationship (XFN)" field.

Comment: Yes, Can you help me on this??

Comment: sure, but which part do you need help with?

Comment: In jquery, I have added custom class in menu (like funny, news are menu options I have added class trending-funny, trending-news). Now I want to show related content on hover like in above of my code.

Comment: @dev, can you please give a link to development site's url or give the codes you worked so far?

Comment: Hmm, currently I am on my local, But I have added code in jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5yogz94y/

Comment: @dev, can you please check my answer again. I edited it. I think this will work as you want.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for helping me. :)